# Dart: Map add more entries from Map with different subtype

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying add Map entries to the existing Map, by adding a Map entries with different subtype. But I cant figure out how should I do it. Currently I am having this error.

`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, _Tag>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<int, String>' of 'other'`

```
class AppController{
  Map<dynamic,_Tag> _list = new Map<dynamic,_Tag>();

  Map<dynamic,_Tag> getList(){return _list;}


  void addList(Map<dynamic,String> val){
    this._list?.addAll(val.map((index, value)=>MapEntry(index, _Tag(index: index, value: value))));
  }

  void setSelected(Map<dynamic,String> val){
    this._list?.addAll(val.map((index, value)=>MapEntry(index, _Tag(index: index, value: value, selected: true))));
  }

}
```

```
class _Tag{
  bool selected = false;
  final dynamic index;
  final String value;
  _Tag({this.index, this.value, this.selected});
}
```

I called it this way,

```
TagsWidget({this.title,this.controller, Map<dynamic,String> list , Map<dynamic,String> selected}){
    this.controller.addList(list);
    this.controller.setSelected(selected);
  }

AppController tagsCtrl = new AppController();
Map<int, String> options = {
    1:'Option 1',
    2:'Option 2',
    3:'Option 3',
    4:'Option 4',
    5:'Option 5'
};

TagsWidget(
            title: 'Title herer',
            list: this.options ,
            selected: this.options ,
            controller: tagsCtrl ,
          )
```

Comment: This works for me.. check out https://dartpad.dartlang.org/163937d127871cfb51797048374ffb61 and tell me what needs to change to reproduce your problem

Comment: I tried also myself, and it works in my local environment. Can you show the method that calls AppController.addList() ? I assume that function produces this issue

Comment: @BrianGorman I updated my description

Comment: @ejabu I updated my description.

Comment: I dont know what happend but when I test it now, it just worked. hahaha Maybe I should have restart the dart itself. thanks anyway.

Comment: glad it solved by itself. however I make suggestion to change _Tag definiton to this : class _Tag {
  bool selected;
  final dynamic index;
  final String value;
  _Tag({this.index, this.value, this.selected = false});
}